# Use different css or java script per page with freemarker

Tags: freemarker

Using FreeMarker, I would like to be able to load different stylesheets or javascript files in different templates. My problem may be in my implementation.

I have a single layout macro which looks like this:

```html
<#macro layout>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- common javascript and css references here -->
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="container">

      <!-- header stuff -->

      <#nested>

      <!-- footer stuff -->

    </div>
  </body>
</html>

</#macro>
```

I use this in all templates like this:

```html
<!-- "declare" specific css or js here -->
<@layout.layout>

<div id="mapid">

  <!-- use specific css or js -->

</div>

</@layout.layout>
```

In some of my templates I would like to use specific stylesheets or javascript libraries that apply to the common case. What is the best approach for this?

I've tried passing variable in to the layout macro to insert the css and js references but I've found no easy way to assign a block of text using #assign.

Comment: Not sure where do you stuck, or why do you need block assignment (which looks like `<#local foo>...</#local>` or the same with `#assign` or `#global`). First of all, based on what do you want to decide which CSS or JS to include? Like, do you want the MVC Controller to decide that, or do you want to encode that into the template, or do you want it to depend on template location, or... ?

Comment: The decision to include different javascript or css depends on the purpose of the template. For example I have a template that I use to displaying reports. There is no reason for any other template to require the javascript I use for doing that. Thanks for the response. I will investigate <#local>.

Comment: @ddekany I can't see how <#local> will help me. It can only be used in a macro or function. I'm in neither context.

Comment: How about passing the non-common CSS and/or JS names to the `layout` call as an optional parameter? Something like `<@layout.layout css="foo.css" js="foo.js">`. (I didn't say you need block assignment, I have asked why do you need it. As of the scope of `#local`, you can do the same with `#assign` and `#global`.)

Comment: Thats the same solution I came up with. It seems to be working.

Answer (score 1):

You can declare nested tags and send as a parameter the name like this:

layout.ftl

```
<#macro layout>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- common javascript and css references here -->
    <#nested "styles">
    <#nested "scripts">
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="container">

      <!-- header stuff -->

      <#nested "content">

      <!-- footer stuff -->

    </div>
  </body>
</html>

</#macro>
```

And then you can receive as a parameter the section and use an if like this:

page.ftl

```
<@layout.layout; section>
<#if section = "scripts">
     <script src="/js/myscripts/myfile.js"></script>    
</#if>
<#if section = "styles">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/style.css" /> 
</#if>

<#if section="content">
  <div id="mapid">

  </div>
</#if>

</@layout.layout>
```

Answer (score 0):

I separated the layout into page start end page end, and define the nested in page start.

page_start.ftl

```html
<#macro external>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head lang="en">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>${title}</title>
    <meta name="keywords" content="${keyword}">
    <meta name="description" content="${description}">

    <link href="https://cdn.insdep.com/themes/1.0.0/easyui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="https://cdn.insdep.com/themes/1.0.0/easyui_animation.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.insdep.com/jquery/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.insdep.com/easyui/jquery.easyui-1.5.1.min.js"></script>

    <#nested >

</head>
<body>

    <#include "global/header.ftl">

    <#include "global/sidebar.ftl">

</#macro>
```

page_end.ftl

```html
<#include "global/footer.ftl">

</body>
</html>
```

```html
<#import "page_start.ftl" as page>
<@page.external>
    <link href="https://cdn.insdep.com/themes/1.0.0/easyui_plus.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</@page.external>
hello world

<#include "page_end.ftl">
```

But I do think, this is not a very decent solution.